# Search a pandas column in df2 for text contained in each cell of a separate pandas df column (df1), then return the contents of another df2 column

Tags: python, pandas, string, search, comparison

Using the sample tables below I'm looking for each cell in df1['A'] to be searched for in df2['name'] (maybe using str.endswith), then for the value in the df2 'Code' cell on the same row of the match to be added to the relevant row in df1

df1:

| A |
| --- |
| Test - Search |
| Test - Search2 |
| Another Search |
| Test - Search |

df2:

| name | Code |
| --- | --- |
| blah blah Test - Search | AAA100 |
| And another | www456 |
| blah blah Search text | HGT100 |
| random text Test - Search2 | BBB100 |
| Another Search | dsw542 |

Required Result of df1:

| A | Code |
| --- | --- |
| Test - Search | AAA100 |
| Test - Search2 | BBB100 |
| Another Search | dsw542 |
| Test - Search | AAA100 |

Ideally this can be accomplished without iterating through the DataFrame but not sure if this is possible and if it is not possible still looking for the best solution using iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best optimal way, as I did with iteration only;

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A":['Test - Search','Test - Search2','Another Search','Test - Search']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"name":['blah blah Test - Search','And another','blah blah Search text','random text Test - Search2','Another Search'],
                    "code":['AAA100','www456','HGT100','BBB100','dsw542']})

code = [] 
for text in df1["A"]:
    df2["temp"] = df2["name"].apply(lambda x: x[-len(text):])
    df3 = df2[df2["temp"] == text]
    if df3.shape[0] > 0:
        code.append(df3.iloc[0,1])
    else:
        code.append("")
df1["code"] = code

# Output of df1

                A    code
0   Test - Search  AAA100
1  Test - Search2  BBB100
2  Another Search  dsw542
3   Test - Search  AAA100
```

Hope this Helps...

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. Using A extract and dropna to achieve the desired results.

```
(df2
 .assign(name=lambda x: x.name.str.extract(f"({'|'.join(x for x in sorted(df1.A, key=len, reverse=True))})"))
 .dropna()
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution @William Rosenbaum I have a couple of questions. When I run this code with a test df1 containing 3357 rows the result when saved to df3 for example only contains 226 rows, every entry in df1['A'] has a corresponding entry in df2['name'] so I don't understand the cause of the row reduction. Any ideas? This appears to add df['A'] into df2 and with the simplistic examples above it would be simple to take a copy of df2 then drop the name column to get the end result. However what I really need is df2['Code'] to be added into df1 (where the strings match). Is this possible?